# What does referred to mean in induction motors?

Tags: induction-motor

What does the term referred to mean?
And how if it's a stator reactance it still says referred to stator?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's talking about to the transformer ratio between stator and rotor windings. So for a 1:2 transformer, a resistor on the secondary ends up with the effect of half the voltage and double the current on the primary which makes it appear as a half the resistance when viewing it through the primary side. It's been "referred" to the primary.

Comment: @DKNguyen is there a transformer ratio in motors?

Comment: I should have said "turns ratios similar to that in a transformer". But a lot of motors are just a bunch of coils interacting and moving past each other which makes them rotating transformers in one way or another. The main difference is that in a motor the coils can move past each other whereas in a normal transformer they are fixed relative to one another.

Comment: You have a rotor winding and a stator winding coupled by a magnetic circuit. Looks very much like a transformer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *And how if it's a stator reactance it still says referred to stator?*

That's a typo - it should say *rotor leakage reactance (referred to stator)*.

The term referred comes from transformers. If you have an N:1 step-down transformer then a 1 Ω load on the secondary is seen to behave like an \$N^2\$ load at the primary. Hence the term referred.

> *is there a transformer ratio in motors?*

There certainly is inside induction motors and it's usually in the realm of 1000:1 stepping down from stator to rotor.